# Import XML to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xml

I need to create Mysql tables using this XML but i can't find the way to import all the child's data.

This is the XML.

```
<product>
    <ref>2101</ref>
    <name>VERSALLES</name>
    <printjobs>
        <printjob>
            <teccode>100115</teccode>
            <tecname>TAMPOGRAFÍA E
            </tecname>
            <areas>
                <area>
                    <areacode>384</areacode>
                    <areaname>En la tapa</areaname>
                </area>
            </areas>
        </printjob>
        <printjob>
            <teccode>101200</teccode>
            <tecname>TERMOGRABADO SECO
            </tecname>
            <areas>
                <area>
                    <areacode>488</areacode>
                    <areaname>Esquina inferior derecha de la portada</areaname>
                </area>
            </areas>
        </printjob>
            <printjob>
            <teccode>101201</teccode>
            <tecname>TERMOGRABADO CINTA COLOR
            </tecname>
            <areas>
                <area>
                    <areacode>488</areacode>
                    <areaname>Esquina inferior derecha de la portada</areaname>
                </area>
            </areas>
        </printjob>
    </printjobs>
</product>
<product>
    <ref>2233</ref>
    <name>1L</name>
    <printjobs>
        <printjob>
            <teccode>100115</teccode>
            <tecname>TAMPOGRAFÍA E
            </tecname>
            <areas>
                <area>
                    <areacode>259</areacode>
                    <areaname>En el cuerpo</areaname>
                </area>
            </areas>
        </printjob>
    </printjobs>
</product>
```

I tried to import using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to create a different table for area, printjob and product but its only imports the first area of every product.

This is the SQL that i used for area.

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/allprintdatafile_esp.xml'
    INTO TABLE areas
    CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
    LINES STARTING BY '<product>' TERMINATED BY '</product>'
    (@product)
    SET
    id = NULL,
    id_area = ExtractValue(@product, '//areacode'),
    id_print_job = ExtractValue(@product, '//teccode'),
    id_product = ExtractValue(@product, '//ref'),
    areaname = ExtractValue(@product, '//areaname'),   
);
```

Once imported I need the table to look like this.

| id | id_area | id_print_job | id_product | areaname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 384 | 100115 | 2101 | En la tapa |
| 2 | 488 | 101200 | 2101 | Esquina inferior derecha de la portada |
| 3 | 488 | 101201 | 2101 | En la tapa |
| 4 | 259 | 100115 | 2233 | En el cuerpo |

Thank you.

Comment: [LOAD XML Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html)

Comment: Provide desired final data state after importing this XML.